# I want open html page in a div but I can't

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a problem. I want to load a `aspx` page in a div. How can I do this? I know that is possible in frame but for my situation I must use just div.
Exemple:

```
<div id="myDiv">... here I want to download Debitor_Edit.aspx page ....</div>
```

I will be pleased if you will give me some easy solution to resolve my problem

I'm using this one:

```
$('#myDiv').load('Debitors_Edit.aspx');
```

But not working. Maybe exist a few different solutions or I must write something more?

Comment: are both of the pages in same doamin or different?

Comment: This two pages is in one project but in the different folders.Domain is the same

Comment: Then you need to specify the file path. Use your console tool in the browser that you're developing in and it will show you errors when a file is not found.

Comment: Same queestion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099214/how-to-display-an-aspx-in-another-aspxs-div-dynamically-at-runtime

PS : You cannot load an .aspx page in other aspx's page div. 
    You can just replace the html using ajax or you can use Usercontrols!