# Advanced iframe solution from external source

Tags: iframe

Oki, I got my head on the table here.

I'm trying to get contents from another page, and interact with it. Using some kind of advanced *iframe* solution.

Up until now I've been using the ugly *iframe* solution, you can see the results here : 
http://www.mosfellsbaer.is/stjornkerfi/stjornkerfi/fundargerdir/
Please try to interact with it to see how ugly this is.

Ok..

I found another page that uses the same system as we do, but it looks a lot better.
It's an *iframe*, but when looking at the source code, I dont see any *iframe* embed code or anything that points to that it's an *iframe*. Here is the page : 
http://www.kopavogur.is/stjornsyslan/fundargerdir/searchmeetings.aspx

But I know this is some kind of an *iframe*.

Their way is a bit better because they can use their own css and such.

Somehow they get the contents from the searchmeetings.aspx and post it to their page

How the h... are they doing this ?

I'm kind of new at this here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not an iframe... Looks like they're doing something like this: [How to display an ASPX in another ASPX's DIV dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099214/how-to-display-an-aspx-in-another-aspxs-div-dynamically-at-runtime)

It's an ASP page, and the inserted document has a few clues telling us that it's a Microsoft generated page as well:

```
    <div class="boxbody">



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Leit í fundargerðum</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
        <link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </HEAD>
    <body>
```

Comment: the system that is inside the iframe is microsoft product

Comment: They're not using an iframe, or there would be an iframe tag there. JavaScript eventually loads four iframes on their page: 3 from Facebook and one from Twitter. ASP is inserting the other page before any JavaScript runs.

Comment: oki thank you for that , but this does not get me any closer on solving my problem.

Comment: would file_get_contents work in this situation ? the visitor needs to stay on our page

Comment: In the link I posted above, there's a link to a solution called UFRAME. Here's a page that demonstrates its use and explains what it is (not an iframe, just populates a div) http://labs.omaralzabir.com/UFrame2005/